# Cómo importar modulos fuera del directorio padre

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Tengo un proyecto realizado en Python que al ejecutarlo con el IDE PyCharm 2017.3.4 Community Edition (instalado como snap) funciona y se ejecuta correctamente.

La estructura es la siguiente:

```
mrz/
├── base
│   ├── countries_ops.py
│   ├── countries.py
│   ├── errors.py
│   ├── functions.py
│   └── string_checkers.py
├── checker
│   ├── fields.py
│   ├── hash_fields.py
│   ├── honorifics.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── report.py
│   ├── td1.py
│   ├── td2.py
│   └── td3.py
├── generator
│   ├── dictionaries
│   │   ├── arabic.py
│   │   ├── cyrillic_belarussian.py
│   │   ├── cyrillic_bulgarian.py
│   │   ├── cyrillic_macedonian.py
│   │   ├── cyrillic.py
│   │   ├── cyrillic_serbian.py
│   │   ├── cyrillic_ukrainian.py
│   │   ├── greek.py
│   │   ├── hebrew.py
│   │   └── latin_based.py
│   ├── fields.py
│   ├── hash_fields.py
│   ├── holder_name.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── td1.py
│   ├── td2.py
│   ├── td3.py
│   └── transliterations.py
├── gitscript.sh
├── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── test.py
├── tests
│   ├── functions
│   │   └── open_image.py
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── id_cards
│   │   │   ├── Latvia.png
│   │   │   ├── ... borrados algunos para acortar ...
│   │   │   └── Sweden.png
│   │   ├── other
│   │   │   ├── TD2_ICAO_Example.png
│   │   │   └── USA_Border_Crosser.png
│   │   ├── passports
│   │   │   ├── Canada.png
│   │   │   ├── ... borrados algunos para acortar ...
│   │   │   └── Ukraine.png
│   │   └── resident_cards
│   │       ├── France.png
│   │       ├── ... borrados algunos para acortar ...
│   │       └── USA.png
│   ├── mrz_checker_test
│   │   ├── c_id_card_esp.py
│   │   ├── ... borrados algunos para acortar ...
│   │   └── id_card_bad.py
│   └── mrz_generator_test
│       ├── id_card_lie.py
│       ├── ... borrados algunos para acortar ...
│       └── td2_uto.py
└── unittest1.py
```

Los archivos que se ejecutan son los td1.py, td2.py y td3.py en los módulos generator y checker.. cada uno con su **init**.py correspondiente. Es decir, importo alguna de las clases alojadas en generator/td1.py, generator/td2.py, generator/td3.py, checker/td1.py, checker/td2.py y checker/td3.py.

Hasta aquí todo correcto. Puedo ejecutarlo sin problemas desde el IDE o desde la consola BASH de comandos siempre y cuando lo haga desde el directorio padre.

El problema está en que cuando intento ejecutar cualquiera de los ejemplos  ubicados en la carpeta "tests" fuera de los directorios de trabajo padre ("generator" y "checker") desde la línea de comandos siempre obtengo ImportError. Por ejemplo, desde tests/mrz_checker_tests/id_card_bad.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from checker.td1 import TD1CodeChecker

mrz_td1 = ("I<BAD<BAD<<<<<0<<<<<<BAD<<<<<<\n"
           "0105998<0512868BAD<<<<BAD<<<<0\n"
           "<SPECIMEN1<<SPECIMEN2<<BAD<<<<")

td1_check = TD1CodeChecker(mrz_td1)

assert bool(td1_check) is False
```

Si lo ejecuto desde la línea de comandos obtengo como salida el siguiente error:

```
$ ./id_card_bad.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./id_card_bad.py", line 4, in <module>
    from checker.td1 import TD1CodeChecker
ImportError: No module named 'checker'
```

En cambio, ejecutándolo desde el IDE funciona correctamente, obteniendo esta salida:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/ivan/Escritorio/PyCharmProjects/mrz/tests/mrz_checker_test/id_card_bad.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

He intentado anexar el directorio donde se encuentra el módulo al inicio del ejemplo id_card_bad.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(sys.path[1] + "/checker")
```

Pero sigo obteniendo los mismos resultados: funciona correctamente desde el IDE pero obtengo un ImportError ejecutándolo desde la terminal.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Cómo debería importar o qué se debería hacer para poder ejecutar un módulo fuera del directorio padre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un poco de perseverancia y, en parte, gracias a los datos @jaumebonet, creo que di con la solución

El problema está en como se abre el proyecto desde el IDE: utilizando un enlace en vez de la ruta completa hacia el proyecto.

Por lo que parece $PYTHONPATH no acepta enlaces simbólicos.

Es decir, la solución de @jaumebonet funciona si se abre el proyecto desde la ruta real y al inicio del script se añade:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(sys.path[1])
```

De otra forma se debe utilizar la ruta completa:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/media/ivan/Acer/Users/ivanr/Proyectos/Python/PyCharmProjects/mrz/")
# Aquí sys.path[1] == "/home/ivan/Escritorio/PyCharmProjects/mrz" y era lo que fallaba
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva como solución.

Answer (score 2):

No estoy 100% seguro de si ese es el problema, pero para añadir una libreria a tu `$PYTHONPATH` debes poner el path anterior a su directorio.
Asi, si tu libreria esta en `/path/to/lib/mrz/checker` y quieres añadirla dinamicamente en el script, debes hacer:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/lib/mrz")
```

sin llegar a añadir el directorio de la libreria. Python reconoce la libreria por el nombre del directorio.

**EDIT**

OK, he generado el siguiente arbol de directorio:

```
schema
├── checker
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── td1.py
└── tests
    └── mrz_checker_test
        └── id_card_bad.py
```

que debería ser el mismo.

**`__init__.py`** está vacio.

*td1.py:*

```
class TD1():
  pass
```

*id_card_bad.py:*

```
#!/Users/bonet/local/envs/py3/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.append("/Volumes/MiniTwo/sandbox/pytest/schema/")
from checker.td1 import TD1

a = TD1()
```

todo esto fuera de mi `PYTHONPATH`, y no recrea el error, la verdad es que estoy un poco confuso respecto a porqué en tu caso no carga correctamente el módulo.

Comment: Hola Jaume, muchas gracias por responder. He probado con `sys.path[1]' , en este caso sys.path.append("/home/ivan/Escritorio/PyCharmProjects/mrz") con el mismo resultado

Comment: me dejas parado, la verdad... no debería importar, pero.. veo que desde el IDE, el script se ejecuta `/usr/bin/python3.5  ..../id_card_bad.py` mientras que tu lo llamas como `./id_card_bad.py`? Está tu `/usr/bin/python3` apuntando al 3.5? has probado de llamar el script del mismo modo en el que lo hace el IDE? Me parecería raro que funcionara, pero por probar...

Comment: creo que ya he encontrado la respuesta, en parte, gracias a ti. Ahora la publico. Saludos

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Jaume, creo que el error se debía a que, en vez de utilizar la ruta real, utilizaba un enlace. Si en vez de `/Volumes/MiniTwo/sandbox/pytest/schema/` utilizases un enlace, por ej., `/Volumes/MiniTwo/schema/` puede que reprodujeras el error. (al menos es lo que a mí me sucede)

Comment: Interesante, quizá un link no puede estar en el `PYTHONPATH`... bueno es saberlo...